# On RHEL 6 how can I install a pre-packaged Emacs 25?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, emacs

On RHEL 6.9 (Oracle derivation)  how can I install a pre-packaged Emacs version 25?

In `yum` the standard search (incl. Spacewalk server) gives me only Emacs version 23.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To date (Sep2017) no pre-build RHEL package of Emacs 25 seems to exist. My workaround was to install Emacs 25 from source:

1. Make sure the following development packages are installed via `yum`:

   `gtk+-devel, gtk2-devel, libXpm-devel, libpng-devel, giflib-devel, libtiff-devel, libjpeg-devel, ncurses-devel, gpm-devel, dbus-devel, dbus-glib-devel, dbus-python, GConf2-devel, pkgconfig, libXft-devel` and the `"Development Tools"` group
2. Then download the latest stable emacs sourcres (at this time [`ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/emacs/emacs-25.2.tar.xz`](https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/emacs/emacs-25.2.tar.xz))
3. Then do the usual install "dance":

   ```
   tar xvJf  emacs-25.2.tar.xz
   cd emacs-25.2
   ./configure
   make all
   sudo make install
   ```

Now you have in `/usr/local/bin/emacs-25.2` a shiny new emacs executable.